# Highlight differences by changing specific characters to a different color, using Range.Characters.Font

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare the text in two columns and highlight differences by changing specific characters to a different color, using the *Range.Characters.Font* object property.

The color formatting code seems to break whenever the cells being formatted include numbers.

Here’s the code I’m using to set the character formatting:

```vb
If foundPos > 0 Then
    If typeFlag = True Then  'Mark text red for True flag, blue for False flag
        xCell.Characters(foundPos, Len(subStr)).Font.Color = vbRed
    Else
        xCell.Characters(foundPos, Len(subStr)).Font.Color = vbBlue
    End If
End If
```

The goal is to highlight only those characters which are different by specifying the starting position `foundPos` and number of characters to change `Len(subStr)`.

With ordinary strings this works.

When numbers are involved, like the examples below, the code will only change the text color if the starting position is 1, and even then it will only change the color of all characters in the cell regardless what is specified for length.
If the starting position is anything other than 1, the text doesn’t change color at all.

At first I thought this might be because the cell is formatted as a number, but `xCell.NumberFormat = "@"` to convert it to text before trying to set the color did not change the behavior.
I observe the same behavior when trying to modify any other `.Font` attribute, like Bold or Italics.
The numbers in the cells are hand-typed, not formulas.

I reviewed other questions on Stack Exchange discussing the Range.Characters property, but none that I found specifically address an issue changing the color of a subset of digits within a number cell.

[image: Example Output]

Comment: How exactly did you set the cell format?  Via code?  You may need to re-assign the value after setting the format.  Coloring a subset of characters in a text-formatted numeric value works for me.

Comment: Less code: `xCell.Characters(foundPos, Len(subStr)).Font.Color = IIf(typeFlag, vbRed, vbBlue)`

Comment: By default a text value will be left-aligned, and numbers are right-aligned, so your screenshot values all seem to be numbers.

Comment: Adding to @TimWilliams comment above, you need to re-assign the value *as text* for example `xCell = Format(xCell, "@")`

Comment: @TimWilliams and kevin, thanks for your inputs. You helped me understand that this is a limitation of the way Excel treats numbers. There seems to be no way to get it to highlight specific digits in a number without fully converting to text, so I've tweaked my code to check for and make an exception for numeric cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting, I would add ' at the beginning of a cell. The .NumberFormat = "@" seems affect the formatting of the cell only, not how Excel treats its contents.
Check code below:

```
Sub Highlight_Main()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = GetLastRow()
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        ProcessCells i
    Next i
End Sub

Function GetLastRow() As Long
    GetLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
End Function

Sub ProcessCells(ByVal row As Long)
    Dim cellA As Range, cellB As Range
    Set cellA = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1)
    Set cellB = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 2)
    
    PrepareCell cellA
    PrepareCell cellB
    
    ColorDifference cellA, cellB, vbRed
    ColorDifference cellB, cellA, vbBlue
End Sub

Sub PrepareCell(ByRef cell As Range)
    If IsNumeric(cell.Text) Then cell.Value = "'" & cell.Text
    cell.Characters.Font.color = vbBlack
End Sub

Sub ColorDifference(ByRef mainCell As Range, ByRef compareCell As Range, ByVal color As Long)
    Dim i As Long, foundPos As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(mainCell.Text)
        If i > Len(compareCell.Text) Or Mid(mainCell.Text, i, 1) <> Mid(compareCell.Text, i, 1) Then
            foundPos = i
            mainCell.Characters(foundPos, 1).Font.color = color
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that this will really convert the content of the cell to string. Easy to convert it back if running on same computer or any computer with the same regional settings, but doomed to fail when opening the file on a computer where the regional settings are different. Also, you will loose the possibility to display trailing `0` as a string cannot be formatted